controle do ciclo de vida ao implementar autenticação com google
O emit metodo dos view models crasha apos sync da dependencia "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.2.0" .  Entao, quando tentando executar uma função que trata dos estados do fragmento recebo o erro:
One type argument expected. Use 'Loading<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments 
One type argument expected. Use 'Error<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments 
One type argument expected. Use 'Success<*>' if you don't want to pass type arguments

O que complica tratar os ciclos dos Fragments, e me põe num deadlock porque não consigo avançar na implementação de autenticação.
**Editado: Tentar usar a versão 21.2.0 do gms:play-services-auth estava gerando conflitos com a lib de Lifecycle 2.8.3 (atualmente ultimas versões). Enfim, consegui estabilidade sincronizando com gms:play-services-auth 20.6.0 e Lifecycle 2.8.3
Fragment
    @AndroidEntryPoint class ForgotFragment : Fragment() { 
         private var _binding: FragmentForgotBinding?  = null
         private val binding get() = _binding!!
        private val viewModel: ForgotViewModel by viewModels()
        override fun onCreateView(
             inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
             savedInstanceState: Bundle?
         ): View {
             _binding = FragmentForgotBinding. inflate( inflater,  container, false)
             return binding.root
         }
    
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onViewCreated( view,  savedInstanceState)
            initListeners()
         }
        private fun initListeners() {
             with (binding) {
                 btnForgot.setOnClickListener { validateData() }
             }
             Glide
                .with(requireContext( ) )
                  .load(R.drawable.loading)
                  .into(binding.progressLoading)
          }
    
        private fun validateData() {
             val email = binding.editEmail.text. toString( )
              if (email.isEmailValid( ) )  {
                 hideKeyboard()
                 forgot(email)
             } else {
                 showSnackBar(getString( R. string. text_ email_ invalid) )
              }
         }
    
    
        // aqui, o metodo começa a reclamar que agora eu preciso declarar um tipo para lidar com os estados
         private fun forgot(email: String) {
             viewModel.forgot(email).observe( viewLifecycleOwner)  { stateView ->
                 when (stateView) {
                     is StateView.Loading -> {
                         binding.progressLoading.isVisible = true
                     }
                     is StateView.Success -> {
                         binding.progressLoading.isVisible = false                      
                         showSnackBar("Mock Success")
                     }
                     is StateView.Error -> {
                        binding.progressLoading.isVisible = false
                        showSnackBar("Mock Error")
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
    
         override fun onDestroyView() {
             super.onDestroyView( )
              _binding = null
         }
     }

View Model
    @HiltViewModel
     class ForgotViewModel @Inject constructor(
         private val forgotUseCase: ForgotUseCase
     ) : ViewModel() {
    
        fun forgot(email: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO)  {
             try {
    
                 //emit é o método que muda de comportamento após a adição da dependencia
    
                emit(StateView.Loading( )) 
                forgotUseCase(email) 
                emit(StateView.Success( Unit))
              } catch (e: Exception) {
                 emit(StateView.Error(e.message))
              }
         }
    }

sealed class StateView
    sealed class StateView<T>(
         val data: T? = null,
         val message: String? = null ) {
    
        class Loading<T> : StateView<T>(data = null, message = null)
        class Error<T>(message: String?) : StateView<T>(message = message)
        class Success<T>(data: T, message: String? = null) :
             StateView<T>(data = data, message = message)
    }


O problema está relacionado à necessidade de especificar o tipo ao usar StateView. Para resolver isso, você precisa atualizar a implementação do ViewModel e do Fragment para trabalhar corretamente com os tipos genéricos. Vou ajustar o código para refletir essa mudança:
ViewModel
Primeiro, vamos ajustar o ForgotViewModel para emitir StateView com o tipo apropriado:
@HiltViewModel
class ForgotViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val forgotUseCase: ForgotUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    fun forgot(email: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            emit(StateView.Loading<Unit>())
            forgotUseCase(email)
            emit(StateView.Success(Unit))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            emit(StateView.Error<Unit>(e.message))
        }
    }
}

Fragment
Agora, vamos ajustar o ForgotFragment para lidar com o tipo genérico:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ForgotFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentForgotBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel: ForgotViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentForgotBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initListeners()
    }

    private fun initListeners() {
        with(binding) {
            btnForgot.setOnClickListener { validateData() }
        }
        Glide
            .with(requireContext())
            .load(R.drawable.loading)
            .into(binding.progressLoading)
    }

    private fun validateData() {
        val email = binding.editEmail.text.toString()
        if (email.isEmailValid()) {
            hideKeyboard()
            forgot(email)
        } else {
            showSnackBar(getString(R.string.text_email_invalid))
        }
    }

    private fun forgot(email: String) {
        viewModel.forgot(email).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { stateView ->
            when (stateView) {
                is StateView.Loading -> {
                    binding.progressLoading.isVisible = true
                }
                is StateView.Success -> {
                    binding.progressLoading.isVisible = false
                    showSnackBar("Mock Success")
                }
                is StateView.Error -> {
                    binding.progressLoading.isVisible = false
                    showSnackBar("Mock Error")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

Sealed Class
Finalmente, vamos garantir que a classe StateView esteja definida corretamente para aceitar tipos genéricos:
sealed class StateView<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null
) {
    class Loading<T> : StateView<T>()
    class Error<T>(message: String?) : StateView<T>(message = message)
    class Success<T>(data: T, message: String? = null) : StateView<T>(data = data, message = message)
}

Com essas mudanças, você deve ser capaz de lidar corretamente com os tipos genéricos no ViewModel e no Fragment, evitando os erros que você mencionou. Certifique-se de que todas as dependências estejam corretamente sincronizadas e compatíveis.

Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.
